# Is there a way to make Recyclerview Scrollbar thumb of fixed height?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollbar

I don't want my custom scrollbar thumb to grow and shrink with the list size. While it worked with `ListView` and `GridView`, I can't find any way of doing it with `RecyclerView`.

I could find fast scrollers for linear layout but they are not working with gridlayout. As for example, I am using [RecyclerViewFastScroller library](https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller).

but it doesn't work with `GridLayoutManager` as nicely as it does with `LinearLayoutManager`. So my question is twofold

1. Is there a way of getting the scrollbar thumb from changing its height dynamically?
2. Or is there a library that can implement scrollers with `GridLayoutManager`.